# Set 'durationDays' to 'from the beginning' in firebase dynamic links analytics api

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

Below url is used for fetching analytics data related to firebase dynamic links:
https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/SHORT_DYNAMIC_LINK/linkStats?durationDays=DURATION

(Please note that the above url is an API that needs authentication/token. You can't open it in a browser. Also, SHORT_DYNAMIC_LINK and DURATION are just placeholders not actual parameter values.
The reason I have added a link is because my question is about the value of the placeholder - DURATION present in the link)

DURATION tells how many days(going backwards) worth data needs to be fetched.

My requirement is to fetch data from the start(when the dynamic link was created). So, what value should I set for `durationDays` to achieve that?

As a workaround I can set a big number(like 1000 days) but wanted to know a proper way.

Based on what I tried, the parameter `durationDays` must be present in the url, otherwise the request would return `400 INVALID ARGUMENT`. Even setting DURATION values to `0` or `-1` return a similar error.

Firebase Analytics API Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics

Comment: Can someone explain why this was downvoted? I have provided all the required information.

Comment: It was likely downvoted because including links in the question is discouraged - links break (like that one - doesn't work) and if it does, it invalidates the question. Also, showing the actual code you're using to fetch the analytics data would be appropriate. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2851937/jay I have updated my question. The reason there's no code is because it's not required. After I generate a token, which I am able to do successfully, I have to hit the mentioned url with correct parameter values. My question is about the value of one of those parameters for a specific scenario.

Comment: Understood. Are you storing the dynamic link creation date somewhere?

Comment: Yes!! I can use the minimum of those dynamic links creation dates to find DURATION. Unfortunately there are bunch of dynamic links that were created sometime back and we didn't store their creation date. Thanks @Jay, this solution will work for majority of the dynamic links.

Comment: @Shiva have you found the solution to this ?

Comment: @Md.Nawaz I didn't and currently I am not working on anything Firebase-related.